# Механизмы синхронизации процессов/потоков в UNIX/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, unix, синхронизация

Какие Вы знаете механизмы синхронизации процессов/потоков в UNIX/Linux ? Вопрос с собеседования по С++ на позицию Software Developer

Comment: на этот вопрос гугл вам выдаст ответов целый вагон с тележкой, не ленитесь, поищите сначала там

Comment: ip порты и fifo файлы (их вы вероятно не найдете в сети)

Comment: много разных ))

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Этот пост написан в постновогодней  депрессии/подпитии, так что прошу не обессудьте за искренние эмоций/прямоту и если я что-то забыл.</sub>

---

Пройдёмся по классическим IPC:

Многие из этих вызовов доступно в двух эпостасях: BSD и SysV. Для большинства из таких примитивов на практике первые используются чаще; вторые есть во многих ОС; в основном по историческим соображениям.

1. Сигналы — работать с ними крайне геморройно в силу их асинхронности, так что почти наверняка, если в обработчике сигнала возникает необходимость сделать что-то кроме как установить какой-то флаг, то скорей всего это ошибка.
2. Трубы (*каналы*, *fifo*) — анонимные трубы (`man 2 pipe`) применяются часто; именованные каналы (`man 3 mkfifo`), для передачи данных стороннему процессу — иногда допустимы, но создавать именованный канал для управления текущим — это, скорей всего, ошибка.
3. Сокеты (в особенности `man 2 socketpair` и `man 7 unix`) — это то что используется повсеместно.
4. Очереди ожидания (`man 3 mq_open` `man 2 msgget`) — используется чуть чаще чем никогда; скорей всего, если тебе не нужны приоритеты, то вместо этого тебе нужен сокет.
5. Общая память (`man 2 mmap`; `man 2 shmget`) — используется повсеместно; не то что бы является средством *синхронизации* в узком смысле, но не упомянуть нельзя.
6. Семафоры (`man sem_open`, `man 2 semget`) — см. что такое семафор; в рамках голого posix — незаменимы; на практике могут быть полезны для специфичных задач.
7. Блокировки файлов (`man 2 flock`, `man lockf`, `man fcntl`); внимание: блокировки почти всегда **кооперативные**, т.е. блокируют доступ к файлу, **только** если другой процесс также пытается получить блокировку.
8. futex (`man 2 futex`) — специфично для linux; используются в основном для реализации других примитивов.

Для межпоточной синхронизации есть также примитивы `pthread`:

1. Мьютекс (`man pthread_mutex`)
2. Условная переменная (`man pthread_cond_timedwait`)
3. `Join`'ы *(`man pthread_join`) — способ дождаться окончания потока
4. Барьеры (`man pthread_barrier_init`)
5. Спин-блокировки (`man pthread_spin_init`)

Ну а ещё есть примитив из C++20:

1. Ожидание на условной переменной. В linux оптимально реализуется средствами futex'а.

Comment: Я бы еще упомянул lockf/flock на файлах, ну и не совсем согласен с оценкой fifo (именованные каналы?). У них есть уникальное свойство ожидания визави при open (т.е. это точка рандеву для неродственных процессов)

Comment: @avp, спасибо (забавно как, принято говорить «спасибо» при указании на собственные ошибки… в этом есть какой-то элемент дзен-будизма=)), про блокировки — согласен, добавил; про каналы — уточнил

Comment: Для работы с сигналами можно использовать signalfd и epoll